# Unusual ULN2003A marking

Tags: markings, uln2003

I bought ULN2003A but I am unsure. The marking seems questionable to me. Rude logo and absence of the vertical bar. I can't find anything about the marking from the manufacturer? Anyone to help me?

[image]

Comment: That looks fine to me.  If by "vertical bar" you mean a marking to show the pin 1 end, the circle in the bottom left corner is a common indicator for pin 1.  Some manufacturers may print a vertical bar, and others may have a notch in the pin 1 end.

Comment: I did an acetone test and the marking does not fade.

The dimensions of the case seem correct and the packaging too (real dimension and tape dimension).

Comment: Where did you make the purchase?

Answer (score 2):

The marking looks correct: https://www.ti.com/packaging/en/docs/partlookup.tsp?partmarking=ULN2003A

The dot looks correct:

> [image: typical pin 1 indicators]

But this does not prove anything; the counterfeiter can copy this from a real TI chip.

The only way to be sure to get a real chip is to buy from an authorized distributor. Some random Ebay merchant is not.

Comment: If so, it's a nice fake. I asked Texas and they cannot prove authenticity. More than testing.